# Criterion for galaxy mergers, negative E?

Tags: energy, angular-momentum, astrophysics, orbital-motion, galaxies

[image]

I'm writing about galaxy mergers and came across this section in a book describing criteria for a merger. I don't understand how there can be a negative $\hat{E}$ yet this is the region where mergers can occur, I would appreciate any explanation asap please!

Answer (score 1):

In dynamics, when you're looking at energies you have to define the zero-point: there isn't any *particular*, 'necessary' meaning of $E=0$.  The only thing that effects calculations is *differences* in energies.  It is often very convenient, and almost always the standard practice (when possible), to define $E=0$ as "unbound".  In other words, set $E=0$ to be the energy two gravitating particles would have if they were stationary (no kinetic energy), at an infinite separation (zero potential energy).

Kinetic energy, which makes particles *less* bound is positive, while potential energy which makes particles *more* bound is negative.  So it almost ends up being a tautology that only galaxies with negative energy can collide---because by definition those are the ones that are gravitationally "bound" to each-other.

Being bound (negative energy) is not enough however, because they may just orbit each other is a stable way.  For a stable orbit, they require sufficient angular momentum $L$.  Based on the sizes of the galaxies, there's some critical angular momentum below which they will collide, if they are also bound.